# How to sort a shorter list based on a longer list regardless of uncommon members?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set, filtering

I have two lists of a and b , where a is longer than b and has some common members with b. in the following example, **my desired output** is to have b sorted as :

`b=[1,3,5]`

and also dropping uncommon members out of a.

but using zip and set , I tried in two ways, changing the position of 2 uncommon members of a :6 and 7, and I do not get the same result.

Attention : not always the members are integer, they can be also string

case 1 :

```
a=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

b=[1,22,3,44,5]

a,b= zip(*sorted(zip(a,b)))

a
Out[15]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

b
Out[16]: (1, 22, 3, 44, 5)

set(a)&set(b)
Out[18]: {1, 3, 5}
```

case2:

```
a=[ 6,7,1,2,3,4,5]

b=[1,22,3,44,5]

a,b= zip(*sorted(zip(a,b)))

a
Out[20]: (1, 2, 3, 6, 7)

b
Out[21]: (3, 44, 5, 1, 22)

set(a)&set(b)
Out[22]: {1, 3}
```

Comment: what is your desired output for these 2 cases?

Comment: I have indicated it in the question text, the first one : all of the common members.

Comment: So, how is what you want different from keeping the elements of b who are also elements of a, then sort them?

Comment: I think that was the answer, indicated in the first answer given by CDJB. but I hope it will work for strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list containing the common members by:

```
>>> a=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> b=[1,22,3,44,5]
>>> sorted(set(a)&set(b))
[1, 3, 5]
```

Second example:

```
>>> a=[ 6,7,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=[1,22,3,44,5]
>>> sorted(set(a)&set(b))
[1, 3, 5]
```

Strings:

```
>>> a=['a','c','b','d','e']
>>> b=['c','a','g','4','b']
>>> sorted(set(a)&set(b))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: have you tested with the second example ?

Comment: and with str also ?

Comment: Yes,this approach works for those cases - see updated examples.